# erb内での文字列の長さを制限したい

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, erb

railsのerb内で

```
<%=raw "#{item.title}" %>
```

等とした時に最大文字数を制限したいのですが、どうやれば簡潔に書けるでしょうか？
出来れば下記のように末尾に省略した記号も付けたいところです。

長過ぎるアイテム名 > 長過ぎる…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

truncateメソッドがお探しのメソッドだと思います。

http://railsdoc.com/references/truncate

省略記号はomissionパラメータで指定します。（デフォルトは"..."）  
長さはlengthパラメータで指定します。（デフォルトは30）

```
<%= truncate(item.title, omission: '・・・', length: 20) %>
```

別件ですが、`raw`メソッド（それと`html_safe`メソッドも）を使うとXSS問題を引き起こしかねないので、使わない方ないいと思います。(絶対安全と言い切れる場合は別ですが)

参考情報

- http://asciicasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3

Answer (score 1):

truncateを使用してみてはどうでしょう。
http://railsdoc.com/references/truncate